# Updating a variable from within a loop or conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to update a variable that exists outside of a loop from within the loop like this:

```
var firstRun = true;
console.log("firstRun is " + firstRun);
if(firstRun == true){
    console.log("This is your first run");
    firstRun = false;
}else{
    console.log("You have already run this loop at least once");
};
```

Assuming this code block is within a larger one that would run 4 times I would expect it to output `This is your first run` once, then `You have already run this loop at least once` three times. Instead I get `This is your first run` 4 times and the `console.log("firstRun is " + firstRun);` always outputs `true`

I'm sure this is an issue with scope that I don't quite understand. Forgive me, I come from the land of Ruby :)

Comment: Not if you reassign it to true inside the loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redeclaring `firstRun` every step in the loop. Move `var firstRun = true;` out of the loop.

If you can't move it out of the loop, you'll have to use an object, and check if it's been declared before assigning the object:

```
var firstRun = firstRun || {ran: false};

if (firstRun.ran == true) {
    console.log("This is your first run");
    firstRun.ran = false;
} else {
    console.log("You have already run this loop at least once");
};
```

Comment: This did it. Looks like you can only update an object and not a variable from within a loop in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the boolean is being reset on every iteration. Move the `var firstRun = true;` outside the loop!

```
var firstRun = true;
for (...) {
  if(firstRun){firstRun=false;}
  else{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the `firstRun` variable every time in the loop, so when the conditional statement is executed the value of `firstRun` will always be `true`.

You need to do something like this

```
var firstRun = true;

//Loop only following block
if(firstRun == true){
    console.log("This is your first run");
    firstRun = false;
}else{
    console.log("You have already run this loop at least once");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If that whole block is in your loop, you're going to reset var firstRun = true every iteration.  You'll want to set var firstRun = true outside the loop (right before it for clarity).

```
var firstRun = true;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log("firstRun is " + firstRun);
    if(firstRun == true){
        console.log("This is your first run");
        firstRun = false;
    } else {
        console.log("You have already run this loop at least once");
    };
}
```